# Relationships between top-$k$ eigenvector and top-$k$ singular vector of symmetric matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, symmetric-matrices, singular-values

Is there any relationships of top-$k$ eigenvector and singular vector of symmetric matrix $A \in R^{n \times n}$?

For symmetric matrix $A$

its eigenvalue decomposition is:

$$ A = B \Lambda B^T$$

and its SVD is

$$A = U \Sigma V^T$$

Now I am interesting the top-$k$ ($k \ll n$) corresponding the top-$k$ eigenvalue or singular value.

The top-$k$ eigenvector:$B(1:k,:) \in R^{n \times k}$ and top-$k$ singular vector $U(1:k,:)\in R^{n \times k}$ . Is there any relationships between two matrices?

If given $U(1:k,:)$, can we get $B(1:k,:)$?

Comment: If you compute the eigenvalue decomposition, it *is* a singular-value decomposition, for both $B$ and $B^t$ will be orthogonal. Alas, it's *a* singular value decomposition, not *the* singular-value decomposition (and the same goes for "the" eigenvalue decomposition). In particular, for the identity matrix, $I = Q I Q^t$ for any orthogonal $Q$, so you're asking "Can I, given the eignevalue decomposition $I = RIR^t$, where $R$ is orthogonal, and the SVD, $I = Q I Q^t$, where $Q$ is any other orthogonal matrix, derive $Q$ from $R$ in a systematic way?" The answer's obviously "no."

Comment: Of course, the identity is special in a number of ways, but this should, at the very least, help you formulate a question that has some hope of having a plausible and possibly-useful answer (while recognizing that the answer is very unlikely to be numerically stable).

Comment: @JohnHughes  Cool, so there is not relationship between singular vector and eigenvector for a symmetric matrix?

Comment: I very carefully did *not* say that. What I said was that for certain symmetric matrices, you cannot hope to algorithmically compute an arbitrary diagonalizing matrix from the matrices that appear in an SVD. There are certainly relationships between them in less exceptional cases than the identity.  The top "Related" question on this very page discusses that in some detail.